# Typed method returning its type or undefined. But it shouldn't

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ts-jest

I am creating a function that provides me with an object with methods to set a mocked state for testing.

My issue is that I have typed everything but the object that this method returns is like deleting its type.

this is the interface I am using for the function that provides me the mock state Object with its methods:

```
typescript
interface MockState {
structures: StructuresState;
ui: UiState;
user: UserState;
test: () => PreloadedState<RootState>;
logUser: () => MockState;
setLoadingOn: () => MockState;
turnModalOn: (message: string) => MockState;
turnErrorModalOn: (message: string) => MockState;
setStructures: (total: number) => MockState;
}
```

And this is the function itself.

```
export const mockState = (): MockState => ({
structures: mockStructuresState(),
ui: { ...mockUiState },
user: { ...mockUserState },
 
test() {
return {
structures: { ...this.structures },
ui: { ...this.ui },
user: { ...this.user },
     };
   },
 
 logUser() {
 this.user = { ...loggedUser };
 return this;
   },
 
 setLoadingOn() {
 this.ui.isLoading = true;
 return this;
   },
 
 turnModalOn(message: string) {
 this.ui.modals = { message, error: false };
 return this;
   },
 
 turnErrorModalOn(message: string) {
 this.ui.modals = { message, error: true };
 return this;
   },
 
 setStructures(total: number) {
 this.structures.structures =
 total === 1
 [{ ...structures[0] }]
 [
             { ...structures[0] },
             ...Array(total - 1).fill({ ...structures[1] }),
           ];
 return this;
   },
 });
```

And for more detail these are all the objects I am using:

```
 
 const mockUserState: UserState = { isLogged: false, token: "" };
 
 const mockStructuresState = (): StructuresState => ({
 structures: [],
 currentPage: "0",
 totalPages: 0,
 totalStructures: 0,
 });
 
 const mockUiState: UiState = {
 isLoading: false,
 modals: { error: false, message: "" },
 };
 
 const loggedUser: UserState = {
 isLogged: true,
 token:
     "eyJmsP42OZMDdsrzmY88j1qeHN3mE",
 };
 
 const structures: StructureStructure[] = [
   {
 elevation: "455",
 name: "Bassa",
 type: "Water",
 id: "7342774",
 location: "L",
 image:
       "https://sfxfnjejl.jpg",
 owner: "admin",
 coordenateX: "5689",
 coordenateY: "56789",
 creationTime: "56789",
 description: "its a structure",
   },
   {
 elevation: "450",
 name: "Aljub SN08",
 type: "Construction",
 id: "7342434774",
 location: "L",
 image:
       "https://sfx.jpg",
 owner: "admin",
 coordenateX: "5682329",
 coordenateY: "567892332",
 creationTime: "56789233",
 description: "its another structure",
   },
 ];
```

I think all types are correct but when I call the function and its methods it tells me that the result of that expression is like the interface below:

```
mockState().logUser().setStructures(1).test()



interface typescriptResolution {
  user?: { token: string; isLogged: boolean } | undefined;
  ui?:
    | { isLoading: boolean; modals: { message: string; error: boolean } }
    | undefined;
  structures?: {} | undefined;
}
```

I don't understand why it is telling me that each property can be undefined.

If any of you have any clue of what is going on. Thx

You may see that one of the properties (structures) is filled with a function. But it keeps telling me that the result can be undefined. I tried typing an interface for the return of mockState function and typing the test method with

```
test: () => PreloadedState<RootState>;
```

If it weren't returning this it would show some error, didn't it?

SOLVED

Okey here we go,

The thing is that for the test I dont really need a preloaded state, its opcional, therefore the properties of preloadedState can be undefined. the prolem was that in the test I give to the render an object, and its typed as RouterAndState, I was introducing thre wrong property to this object.

```
export interface RouterAndState {
  ui?: React.ReactElement;
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>;
}
```

Comment: You might want to [edit] the code so that it's easy for others to copy and paste into their own IDEs (unless `>!` is part of the syntax for the code, it should probably be removed)

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the improvements!

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, please [edit] to remove the answer from the question and move it to an answer post below.